# About foreach loop of list of objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't see what's wrong with this code:

```
var listShoppingCart = Session["ShoppingCart"];

foreach (var item in listShoppingCart)
{

}
```

I get a red line below the `listShoppingCart` in the foreach loop. When I hover over the red line, the messages is that Foreach statement cannot operate on variables type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I declare the list with a session like this:

`Session["ShoppingCart"] = new List<Products>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the session object

```
var listShoppingCart = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<Products>;

if (listShoppingCart != null)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

In the above code, we get the object located in the session at key "ShoppingCart" and cast that object to a `List<Products>`. If the cast cannot be done, then `listShoppingCart` will be null.

Comment: Thanks the the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because Session is of Type `HttpSessionState` and this implements `ICollection`.
Session values are stored in `Dictionary<string,object>` which implements `ICollection`. You need to type cast object to appropriate to enumerate over your list.